# AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'Slot'

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am still new to python and I am not sure how to properly connect signals in PyQt5. My code below is done in PyQt4 and Id like to convert it to the newer standard. (Basically I drafted this in a different environment and now Im trying to get it work on this machine)

How do I properly connect my gui elements to each function? Before I connected my button element `pushButtonNext` via:

```
@QtCore.Slot()
def on_pushButtonSolution_clicked(self):
    print('Total Solutions to Display {}'.format(self.total_questions))
```

And to connect menu items I called this within the `__init__`:

```
self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.MenuNew)
self.actionNew.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
```

where `MenuNew()` is as follows:

```
def MenuNew(self):
print('clicked on new')
fileToOpen = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
print(fileToOpen)
if(fileToOpen[0] is not ''):
    print('Change doc')
    self.clearObjects()
    self.setWindowTitle("OpenTester - " + fileToOpen[0])
    #self.convertDocx(fileToOpen[0])
    #self.parse(fileToOpen[0])
    self.displayQuestion(self.test[0],1)
```

For convenience here is my full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# imports for gui
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic, QtGui

#from testevalutils import gui
# imports for parser
import docx2txt

import Question


# Path to the directory containing this .py file (same directory as .ui file)
THIS_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # Calls the QDialog __init__ method with the given parent
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Load the ui file (created by Qt Designer)
        ui_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'MainWindow.ui'))
        uic.loadUi(ui_path, self)

        # initialize test variables
        self.test = []
        self.total_questions = 0
        self.currentQuestion = 0
        self.displayedQuestion = None

        # elements
        self.checkBoxFlag.setText("QUESTION NUM / 999")
        self.textBrowserQuestion.setText("")

        # menu bar
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.MenuNew)
        self.actionNew.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")

    # This decorator (@QtCore.Slot) makes it so this method is automatically
    # connected to the "clicked" signal of the "pushButton_Add" widget by
    # using the naming convention "on_<ObjectName>_<SignalName>"
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_actionNew_clicked(self):
        print('Menu>New clicked')

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_pushButtonSolution_clicked(self):
        print('Total Solutions to Display {}'.format(self.total_questions))

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_pushButtonNext_clicked(self):
        print('Next pushed')
        self.saveState()

        # if not at the last question
        if (self.currentQuestion is self.total_questions):
            print("Finished!")
        else:
            self.currentQuestion = self.currentQuestion + 1
            self.displayQuestion(self.test[self.currentQuestion],1)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_pushButtonBack_clicked(self):
        print('Back pushed')
        self.saveState()
        # go to next question in test array
        self.currentQuestion = self.currentQuestion - 1
        self.displayQuestion(self.test[self.currentQuestion],1)

    # Saves any user changes with check box selections
    # usually called when next or back button is pushed
    def saveState(self):
        checkBoxState = self.checkBoxFlag.isChecked()
        answers = []
        answer1State = self.checkBoxAnswer1.isChecked()
        answers.append(answer1State)
        answer2State = self.checkBoxAnswer2.isChecked()
        answers.append(answer2State)
        answer3State = self.checkBoxAnswer3.isChecked()
        answers.append(answer3State)
        answer4State = self.checkBoxAnswer4.isChecked()
        answers.append(answer4State)
        self.displayedQuestion.SaveState(checkBoxState, answers)
        print('The answer is set to {} {} {} {}'.format(answer1State,answer2State,answer3State,answer4State))

    def disableButton(self, button):
        button.setEnabled(False)

    ### Helper methods ###
    def displayQuestion(self, Question, Number):
        # display question from object we've parsed
        # Add one due to index 0
        num = self.currentQuestion + 1
        self.checkBoxFlag.setText("Question {} of {}".format(num, len(self.test)))
        self.textBrowserQuestion.setText(Question.question)
        self.checkBoxAnswer1.setText(Question.AnswerSetAt(0))
        self.checkBoxAnswer2.setText(Question.AnswerSetAt(1))
        self.checkBoxAnswer3.setText(Question.AnswerSetAt(2))
        self.checkBoxAnswer4.setText(Question.AnswerSetAt(3))

        # load user changes
        self.checkBoxFlag.setChecked(Question.IsFlagged())
        self.checkBoxAnswer1.setChecked(Question.LoadAnswer(0))
        self.checkBoxAnswer2.setChecked(Question.LoadAnswer(1))
        self.checkBoxAnswer3.setChecked(Question.LoadAnswer(2))
        self.checkBoxAnswer4.setChecked(Question.LoadAnswer(3))

        #if first question disable next button
        if(num is 1):
            self.pushButtonBack.setEnabled(False)
        elif (num is self.total_questions - 1):
            self.pushButtonNext.setText("Finish")
        else:
            self.pushButtonBack.setEnabled(True)
            self.pushButtonNext.setText("Next")
        self.displayedQuestion = self.test[self.currentQuestion]
        None

    # Create a txt file "_processed" to read from
    def convertDocx(self, filename):
        rawtext = docx2txt.process(filename + '.docx')
        f = open(filename + '_processed.txt', 'w')
        f.write(rawtext)
        f.close()

    def incrementQuestion(self):
        self.total_questions = self.total_questions + 1

    def addToTest(self, Question):
        self.test.append(Question)

    def clearObjects(self):
        self.test = []
        self.total_questions = 0
        self.currentQuestion = 0
        self.displayedQuestion = 1

    def MenuNew(self):
        print('clicked on new')
        fileToOpen = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
        print(fileToOpen)
        if(fileToOpen[0] is not ''):
            print('Change doc')
            self.clearObjects()
            self.setWindowTitle("OpenTester - " + fileToOpen[0])
            #self.convertDocx(fileToOpen[0])
            #self.parse(fileToOpen[0])
            self.displayQuestion(self.test[0],1)

    # Parse from the txt file
    def parse(self, filename):
        question_block = False
        answer_block = False
        explain_block = False
        with open(filename + '_processed.txt') as openfileobject:
            # set our variable for the question
            q_number = None
            q_question = ""
            q_options = []
            q_answer = None
            q_explain = ""
            for line in openfileobject:
                # line.split('\n')
                # print(line)
                # if only a new line then skip it
                if(line == "\n"):
                    continue
                if (not question_block and "QUESTION" in line):
                    question_block = True
                    q_number = line
                    self.total_questions = self.total_questions + 1
                    # skip to next line to check for its properties
                    continue
                # if found next qustion then get each propertiy and add them
                if(question_block):
                    #keep adding lines until we reach the end
                    if("?") in line:
                        question_block = False
                        answer_block = True
                    q_question = q_question + line
                    continue
                if(answer_block):
                    if("A. " in line or "B. " in line or "C. " in line or "D. " in line):
                        line = line[:-1]
                        q_options.append(line)
                        continue
                    if("Correct Answer:") in line:
                        q_answer = line
                        answer_block = False
                        explain_block = True
                        continue
                if(explain_block):
                    if("Reference" not in line):
                        q_explain = q_explain + line
                        continue
                    else:
                        explain_block = False
                        # Add everything into one question
                        new_question = Question.Question(q_number, q_question, q_options, q_answer, q_explain)
                        self.addToTest(new_question)
                        # Reset our question
                        q_number = None
                        q_question = ""
                        q_options = []
                        q_answer = None
                        q_explain = ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Main function that tests the dialog."""
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    # This ensures errors are reported from GUI callbacks.
    # Otherwise it would
#    gui.handle_unhandled()

    filedocx = 'comptia_practice_3-21-2018'

    # initialize our window along with the test components already
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    w.setWindowTitle("OpenTester - " + filedocx + ".docx")


    w.convertDocx(filedocx)
    w.parse(filedocx)
    # load first question object
    w.displayQuestion(w.test[w.currentQuestion],1)

    # execute app
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: replace @QtCore.Slot() with @QtCore.pyqtSlot()     See http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator

Comment: what is this module of Question ?

Comment: Its nothing special, Question is just an object class with several properties (Number, description, answers, correct answer, and a bool flag). It has basic getters and setters to access these values thats all.

Anyways your solution worked thanks. If you like you can post it as an answer and ill choose is the answer. Thanks.